# When searching for flights, how do I select arrival date, instead of departure date?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, bookings

When booking a long distance flight, the arrival date tends to differ from the date of departure, as it can take 1-2 days to arrive, especially with layovers. If I need to arrive on a specific day, is there a way to filter results based on that needed arrival date?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the website/app you're using. For example, [kayak.com](https://kayak.com) gives you the option to filter the results based on the *landing* date and time.

[image: kayak landingfilter]

Other option which is available in almost all websites/apps, is to sort the results based on the arrival time, scroll up/down and it will be easy to see flights that arrive at a specific day.

Using this method, you will have to redo the search on the same route on a day, the day before and a day after, just to make sure that you cover flights that arrive same day, 1 day after and two days after the departure date.